Can you set the colour of a face depending on the specific transparent face the ray hit prior?
It's a bit tricky to explain, I think? I used a cube and then put a few nodes to have the faces facing the camera be transparent, and the other ones have a specific colour (basically I always see inside the cube).
Now let's say I rotate the camera so I view the cube over a corner (so it looks like a hexagon in orthographic view) - if viewing from above, let's take the bottom face as an example - is there a way to make that face have a different colour depending on the transparent face it's viewed through? Basically I want to know whether the ray from the camera hit the front left face or the front right face of the cube before it hit the bottom side, and set the colour accordingly. I want to do that with all face combinations.
I don't find any node combinations and I think OSL wouldn't help either. I expected that to be straight forward to do


Ah I see what you mean, I think a cheat you could do is to try and figure out a way to have multiple passes composited together. Could try rendering with the colors set for one of the faces, and then add passout on the faces for the other colors. Render out nothing but the inside view of the coloured parts now isolated. Then find a way to recombine the different renders with each differently coloured part back together.

Could you add a screenshot to your question  how you made "the faces facing the camera be transparent"? Is it dependent on the camera's viewing angle towards the face or is it basically inverted just backface culling, so that the front faces are transparent and the backfaces are opaque, i.e. something like mixing a Transparent BSDF with a Principled BSDF and using Geometry > Backfacing as mix factor? And if so how does light get into the cube so that it's not just plain black in there? Sorry if these questions are stupid, but knowing your basic setup might help in finding a solution.

NascentSpace: Sounds like something that could work but I struggle to fully understand since I haven't done any post processing or compositing yet, really
GordonBrinkmann: Yeah I have a mix shader mixing in a transparency using Backfacing (First I tried doing some dot product stuff but just using "Backfacing" worked better). I used the UV texture coordinates to identify each side individually because I thought that would help, but didn't know what to do afterwards.

I added a picture, I haven't even thought about how light should enter... I guess I could put a point light inside, but that doesn't feel like a good solution
